# Ac compressor or bad hoses

Tags: ac, car, compressor

Ac stopped blowing cold air, I was told we needed a new ac compressor. We got it replaced and now it's leaking bright green fluid. Took it back to the dealer they now said its coincidental that the hoses started leaking and we need to replace. I'm at a loss why this wasn't an issue before we replaced the entire compressor

Comment: It could be bad luck. It could be that they bended the hoses a bit more than some old(?) hoses allow. It could be that they damaged the gaskets during install, either by bad luck or negligence. It is difficult to know. Good mechanics offer a heavy discount on those kind of repairs. Others are called "hand-bag-thieves" in our location.

Comment: Unscrupulous dealers and repair shops are everywhere vying for money whether or not they fix what broke. Vehicle ac repair shops are lucrative, preying on many unfamiliar with ac systems  requiring refrigeration knowledge and skills. Reputable repairs are performed by skilled and experienced people. Apparently, this dealer may not have them and rely on replacement artists - replace everything in hopes of fixing a problem while profiting on needless parts. This dealer should have found and informed you of them before  releasing an unfixed repair.